# Fitting a GAM curve over a scatterplot?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, non-linear-regression, gam, loess

I have a scatterplot of total seal abundance (`Total`) against observation period (`Obsv_time`):

```
plot(Total ~ Obsv_time, data = R_Count)
```

I have already created a `gam` exploring total abundance with windspeed and tide:

```
gam.tot <- gam(Total ~ s(Obsv_time, k = 5) + s(Windspeed) + Tide, 
               family = poisson, correlation = corAR1(q=1), 
               data = R_Count)
```

Variables `Total`, `Obsv_time` and `Windspeed` are continuous, while `Tide` is a factor, not sure if this makes a difference?

I would like to fit the `gam` over the scatterplot to show abundance variation over time, I presume using `loess`?

Thanks!

**Update: Solved now, thank you! @patL

Comment: You can add the smoothing from your `gam` by typing `lines(gam.tot, col = "red",  lwd = 2)`. `loess` would work though.

Comment: @patL Thank you for your answer! When I do that it says "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'" ?

Comment: My fault. You have to use `lines(predict(gam.tot...))`